# Export into xml file using "FOR XML AUTO,TYPE, ELEMENTS"

Tags: sql, xml, export

When I execute this code:

```
select client.*
from client
FOR XML AUTO,TYPE, ELEMENT
```

as a query to the database, I get the output as desired, but I need to save it manually.
Is there a way to save it automatically?

And is it possible to schedule this procedure?

I'm kinda new to SQL so take it easy when you anwser please!

Thanks!

Comment: These questions really relate to the environment from which you're calling SQL, rather than to SQL in general. Are you using ODBC? Java? MS SQL Server Management Studio? .NET?

Comment: MS SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 0):

Create a DTS, or if you have a newer version of SQL Server, SSIS package to perform your query and save the results to a file.

Use the SQL Server Agent to schedule a job which runs the package when required.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your awnser. One more question though is it possible for sql server to create a xml specified by a xsd scheme? Or should I do it in for example c# instead?

Comment: I don't know that answer to that but a quick search shows it should be possible. Have a read of this (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/74f83272-67ec-48fe-923b-e520dec9f700/) to see if it answers your question. Also, search for the blog "SSIS Junkie" for loads of help using SSIS.